# int is not printing from variables

Tags: c#, razor

I am gonna try to not make this question to long. I am making email confirmation letters for a hotel.

- If there has been a change in a reservation the red and green sidebar is showing
- If there has not been a change in a reservation, there is just the same background.

The problem is, that it is only the `ArrivalDateTime` and `DepartureDateTime` there is giving me the output in the email. The `orderRooms` and `orderTotalAmmount` is not giving me any output in the email. The code is compiling fine, but I am not getting any output result on the `int`

How can that be?

> ArrivalDateTime       : Printing ArrivalDateTime
>
> DepartureDateTime     : Printing DepartureDateTime
>
> Total number of rooms : Not Printing orderRooms
>
> Total price           : Not Printing orderTotalAmmount

```
<!-- ArrivalDateTime -->
@{
    var orderArrivalDateTime = Model.Order.ArrivalDateTime.ToString("dddd d. MMMM yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK"));
    var order2ArrivalDateTime = Model.Order2.ArrivalDateTime.ToString("dddd d. MMMM yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK"));
    bool hasChangedArrivalDateTime = orderArrivalDateTime != order2ArrivalDateTime;
}
<!-- DepartureDateTime -->
@{
    var orderDepartureDateTime = Model.Order.DepartureDateTime.ToString("dddd d. MMMM yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK"));
    var order2DepartureDateTime = Model.Order2.DepartureDateTime.ToString("dddd d. MMMM yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK"));
    bool hasChangedDepartureDateTime = orderDepartureDateTime != order2DepartureDateTime;
}

<!-- Total number of rooms -->
@{
    var orderRooms = Model.Order.OrderLines.Count;
    var order2Rooms = Model.Order2.OrderLines.Count;
    bool hasChangedorderRooms = orderRooms != order2Rooms;
}
<!-- Total price -->
@{
    var orderTotalAmmount = Model.Order.TotalAmount;
    var order2TotalAmmount = Model.Order2.TotalAmount;
    bool hasChangedorderTotalAmmount = orderTotalAmmount != order2TotalAmmount;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- ArrivalDateTime -->
<table align="center" class="wrapper header float-center">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper-inner">
            @renderOrderPropertyBlock(hasChangedArrivalDateTime, "Arrival", orderArrivalDateTime, order2ArrivalDateTime)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- DepartureDateTime -->
<table align="center" class="wrapper header float-center">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper-inner">
            @renderOrderPropertyBlock(hasChangedDepartureDateTime, "Departure", orderDepartureDateTime, order2DepartureDateTime)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- Total number of rooms -->
<table align="center" class="wrapper header float-center">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper-inner">
            @renderOrderPropertyBlock(hasChangedorderRooms, "Number of nights", orderRooms, order2Rooms)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- Total price -->
<table align="center" class="wrapper header float-center">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper-inner">
            @renderOrderPropertyBlock(hasChangedorderTotalAmmount, "Total price", orderTotalAmmount, order2TotalAmmount)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is a lot more code, but this should be the relevant code to show.

Comment: Try changing your count code from `@renderOrderPropertyBlock(hasChangedorderRooms, "Number of nights", orderRooms.ToString(), order2Rooms.ToString())`

Comment: Since I don't know what rules `wrapper header float-center` applies, they might be behind the date ones. Try removing the data ones, and if you see  count the issue is css.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you a lot :-) Please leave an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `.ToString()` at the end of your integers.
Update your code to use

```
@renderOrderPropertyBlock(hasChangedorderRooms, "Number of nights", orderRooms.ToString(), order2Rooms.ToString())

@renderOrderPropertyBlock(hasChangedorderTotalAmmount, "Total price", orderTotalAmmount.ToString(), order2TotalAmmount.ToString())
```